# Rewriting integrals over a symmetrical set

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, real-numbers

I have $\int_\mathbb{R}f(x)\cdot \mathbf{1}_{A}(x)\,dx$, with $f(x)$ integrable and $A=[-a,-b]\cup[b,a]$.

I rewrote the integral as: $\int_{-a}^{-b}f(x)\,dx+\int_{b}^{a}f(x)\,dx$ but that is annoying to evaluate.

The book rewrites it as: $\int_{-a}^{a}f(x)\,dx-\int_{-b}^{b}f(-x)\,dx$ which is easy to evaluate, but I don't understand why we have a $f(-x)$ in the second term. By my intuition it should be:

$$A=[-a,a]\backslash(-b,b)\Rightarrow\int_Af(x)\,dx=\int_{-a}^{a}f(x)\,dx-\int_{-b}^{b}f(x)\,dx$$

What is wrong with my reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing. Actually both are correct, since
$$
\int_{-b}^b f(u)du = \int_{-b}^b f(-v)dv\ \ \ (\text{with }u=-v) 
$$